# How to get Ajax to load first?

Tags: 7, ajax, webforms, blocks

After updating module `webform_paymethod_select` I noticed that Ajax on webforms stopped working. I was unable to edit any existing webforms or create new ones. This happens when JS Aggregation is enabled. Clearing caches did not help.

Console shows two error messages:

```
TypeError: D.ajax is undefined
  var beforeSerialize = D.ajax.prototype.beforeSerialize;

TypeError: Drupal.ajax is undefined
  Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands['getBlock'] = function(ajax, response, status) {
```

The first error is coming from jQuery update and the second one is coming from the `boxes` module. Disabling boxes module worked for me but it left an important part of my site broken.

I believe the reason is that Ajax is unable to load before `boxes` requires it. After this Ajax just does not load at all.

If anybody can help me out, I would appreciate it.

EDIT:

I couldn't quite figure out how to get Ajax to load before everything. I tried changing its weight in `drupal_add_js()` and modifying `hook_boot()` to get it to load first. This seemed dangerous as i couldn't guarantee that it would only apply to the pages i needed Ajax to be first in. I then turned to figuring out how to encapsulate the `boxes` modules' JavaScript code that was throwing this error. I noticed that the code was being encapsulated with the following:

```
(function ($) {
  ..
})(jQuery);
```

[Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722) suggests using :

```
(function ($) {
  // All your code here
}(jQuery));
```

That didn't work either, so i used the following instead and this made the error go away (except for the error jQuery Update is throwing):

```
jQuery(function($){
  ..
});
```

I am now able to edit existing webforms. I don't really understand why this worked, so if anybody can provide some insight i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It could help.

add php function:

use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;

Class AnyClass extends FormBase {

public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

```
/**
 * Running the library drupal core ajax
 */
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';
```

}

}